# What tool do I use to serialize/deserialize Avro messages stored in a Kafka topic with schema registered in the schema-registry using Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro

I have captured some change data from a MySql database, serialized it with Avro converter and stored it in a Kafka topic. Now I am trying to read back that Avro serialized data from Kafka. I can easily get the serialized data but now I need to deserialize it. How do I do that?

Note: I am using Pyspark to write my spark code. And I am creating a readingStream to stream the data in real-time from the Kafka topic.

I found some tools for Spark(scala libraries) but the same solution for Pyspark is a bit complicated.

I think using Abris https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS is a good choice as it supports for the python version of spark but I cannot seem to properly understand this scala written library's integration in Pyspark(Python). It's a bit complicated as I have not used non-python written libraries in Python.

Does someone have another better alternative for this use case? Another tool maybe. Or can anybody please make me understand this Abris integration for Pyspark. Thank you! https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/blob/master/documentation/python-documentation.md

Comment: If your spark version is 3.0 or later you can use from_avro()